# How to Use pydoc generate documentation for a module with argparse?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, pydoc

I have a python module named `LC_cmdline.py` with argparse as follows.

```
import argparse
import getpass

def get_pass():
    return getpass.getpass("Password: ")
def default_pass():
    return ''

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-u', default='', type=str, metavar='username', dest='username', help="Username for the database")
parser.add_argument('-p', action='store_const', const=get_pass, default=default_pass, dest='get_pass', help="Password for the database")

args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "username: [%s]"%args.username
    print "password: [%s]"%args.get_pass()
```

I tried to convert it to a documentation by pydoc using the command `python -m pydoc -w LC_cmdline`. Then I got this error:

```
usage: pydoc.py [-h] [-u username] [-p]
pydoc.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -w LC_cmdline
problem in LC_cmdline - <type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>: 2
```

Is there a way to generate a documentation for a module with arguments like mine by pydoc? Thank you.

BTW, my OS is win7, and my python is 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd move `parser.parse_args()` inside the `if`, like so:

```
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print "username: [%s]"%args.username
    print "password: [%s]"%args.get_pass()
```

Result:

```
$ pydoc -w LC_cmdline
wrote LC_cmdline.html
```

Comment: What if the file where the parse_args is is imported by another file? It wouldn't be main. This is not a good solution. :(

Comment: @SPL_Splinter, that's actually the point of my answer. OP doesn't want parse_args() called if the file is imported by another file.